# Provider "gs" not installed

Tags: java, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, nio, spring-cloud-gcp

i've found two similar posts here but one hasn't been answered and the other was about android. I have a spring boot project and I want to access GCP Storage files within my application.

Locally everything works fine I can access my bucket and read as well as store files in my storage. But when i upload it to gcp kubernetes I get the following exception:

> "java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "gs" not
> installed     at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:147) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
> at
> xx.xx.StorageService.saveFile(StorageService.java:64)
> ~[classes!/:0.3.20-SNAPSHOT]

My line of code where it appears is like follows:

```
public void saveFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, String path) {
    String completePath = filesBasePath + path;
    
    Path filePath = Paths.get(URI.create(completePath)); // <- exception appears here
    Files.createDirectories(filePath);
    multipartFile.transferTo(filePath);
        
}
```

}

The completePath could result in something like "gs://my-storage/path/to/file/image.jpg"

I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-nio</artifactId>
    <version>0.122.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone have a clue where to look at?
The only real difference except for the infrastructure is that i don't explicitly don't use authentication on kubernetes as it is not required according to the documentation

> When using Google Cloud libraries from a Google Cloud Platform
> environment such as Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine, or App Engine,
> no additional authentication steps are necessary.

Comment: With "locally everything works fine" you mean by running the Spring boot app inside a container or locally on your machine?

Comment: Locally on my machine in eclipse

Comment: So I have been playing around with this. As stated in the answers, the issue is the [spring boot custom jar format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#appendix.executable-jar.nested-jars). Inside `google-cloud-nio` is a file under `META-INF/services`. If I manually copy this file into the spring boot `META-INF/services` then it works fine.
Having my own `resources/META-INF/services` does not work either (because is not in the jar `META-INF`, but is under `classes/META-INF`.
Just using maven assemble plugin works too but opens dependency risks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the conventional Spring boot packaging here isn't packaging the dependency in the needed way. Usually you'll see something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, for the "gs" provider to be accessible it needs to be in the 'lib/' folder. You can package it manually by copying the dependencies and then creating the JAR (this is based on the [springboot-helloworld](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11/springboot-helloworld) sample:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>copy-dependencies</id>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>
                  ${project.build.directory}/lib
              </outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>
              com.example.appengine.springboot.SpringbootApplication
            </mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Originally [posted on GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage-nio/issues/547).

Answer (score 1):

Following [Averi Kitsch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526886/11604596) and using the same [springboot-helloworld](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11/springboot-helloworld) example, I was able to get it working locally after updating pom.xml. However, much like it did for you, it only worked when I ran it locally and would fail when I deployed it on Google Cloud. The issue was that the Dockerfile I was using was ignoring all of the jar files in the /target/lib directory, and I needed to copy that directory to the image. Note that I used Google Cloud Run, but I believe this should work for most deployments using Dockerfile.

Here's what I ended up with:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3.8-jdk-11 as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src

RUN mvn package -DskipTests

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre

COPY --from=builder /app/target/springboot-helloworld-*.jar /springboot-helloworld.jar

# IMPORTANT! - Copy the library jars to the production image!
COPY --from=builder /app/target/lib /lib

CMD ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/springboot-helloworld.jar"]
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>springboot-helloworld</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-nio</artifactId>
      <version>0.123.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>
                ${project.build.directory}/lib
              </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>
                com.example.appengine.springboot.SpringbootApplication
              </mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The gs:// syntax is not universal; it's supported by certain Google tools and services (gsutil, for example) but it's not a known by many URL libraries.

You could change to use the HTTP syntax for one of the GCS APIs, e.g.,

```
https://my-storage.storage.googlapis.com/path/to/file/image.jpg
```

Note that the above HTTP URL will require authentication, so probably instead you would want to use a library like [google-cloud-java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java) that supports making authenticated GCS requests.

Comment: yeah i used the spring lib for gcp storage. i changed to google-cloud-storage later and the problem remains. i don't know why it works locally and not within the cloud itself. I also thought it might be related to the java version, because locally i use jdk 11 and limit it to 8 whereas on k8s i use alpine jdk 8 (this combination created some weird behaviour before) but after upgrading the docker image to jdk 11 nothing has changed too.

Comment: google-cloud-storage also doesn't support that syntax. You should assume nothing does except for the cases you know explicitly do. It's not a widely adopted syntax.

Comment: yes i get that. gs is a special format just for google but i assume it is provided when using one of these dependencies. if i am not completely mistaken the usage is described this way on the offical java-storage-nio github (https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage-nio). apart from that it is still unclear to me where is the difference between my local runtime and my google cloud runtime. locally it works perfectly fine, on k8s it throws the mentioned exception

Comment: @tagtraeumer with "locally it works perfectly fine", do you mean that you tried locally executing the jar app or just from Eclipse? Maybe the jar package you are creating for your app misses something

Answer (score 0):

just mounh the storage bucket in the your server use local path
see below:
https://medium.com/@antrixsh/how-to-mount-cloud-storage-bucket-with-gcp-compute-engine-ba7c95ad5349

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33013502)